# check one radio button with dynamic values

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
<input type="radio" on-click="checkDefaultLanguage" id="checkbox"  >
[[names(name)]]
```

this is my custom input field for radio and has dynamic values in it. I am trying to select one radio at a time and deselect from the others. but I cannot find any information for this. The one I have found are either with name attribute or having static input fields.

my JS

```
private checkDefaultLanguage() {
        const checkboxes = <HTMLInputElement>this.querySelector('#checkbox');

        checkboxes.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (checkboxes.checked) {
              //what is should I do inside of it to make sure only one is selected at a time.
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: <input group="samegroup" /> for all input:radio, it makes only one selected. PS, you are repeating id="checkbox" for all inputs? that a **HUGE** error, read about duplicated id's

Answer (score 1):

Just use name on the input, all input will get assigned to 1 group

```html
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select a maintenance drone</legend>

        <div>
            <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" checked />
            <label for="huey">Huey</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" />
            <label for="dewey">Dewey</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" />
            <label for="louie">Louie</label>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

tbh i dont fully understand what you are trying to do but you could pass the button you just clicked to the function

```
<input type="radio" on-click="checkDefaultLanguage(this)" id="checkbox"  >
```

In your function you could just uncheck every box no matter if it's checked or not.
**After** this for-loop just check the one you passed to the function.